# Xpath not giving correct result

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing

i have an xml file and i am using XPATH to parse it. But i am having problem while getting contents out of it

here is the xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<reg>
  <user>
    <Name>abc def</Name>
    <Email>ahjkhjkghjkhjk</Email>
    <Picture>/mnt/sdcard/download/1357670177a386a-big-1.jpg</Picture>
    <LastEdited>Mar 12, 2014 10:32:09 AM</LastEdited>
  </user>
  <user>
    <Name>xy zabc</Name>
    <Email>asdasdasdasd</Email>
    <Picture>/mnt/sdcard/download/1357670177a386a-big-1.jpg</Picture>
    <LastEdited>Mar 12, 2014 10:32:09 AM</LastEdited>
  </user>
  </reg>
```

and here is my code for parsing it

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder =  builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);

XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();


String expression = "/reg/user/Name";
System.out.println(expression);

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
     System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
     Users_List.add(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
}
```

for this expression `"reg/user"` it return nothing and for `"reg/user/Name"` or `"reg/user/Email"` it returns correct result. i have tested expression with online tester there it gives correct result. is there ant problem with my parsing code..?

Answer (score 1):

The first child of each of your `user` elements is an empty text node, so your `println` statements are probably just printing out nothing. Give this a try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
     System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes()[1].getTextContent());
     Users_List.add(nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes()[1].getTextContent());
}
```

though this is probably better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
     String name = "";
     NodeList nameList = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("Name", nodeList.items(i),
                                                  XPathConstants.NODE);
     if(nameList.getLength() > 0) {
        name = nameList.items(0).getTextContent();
     }
     System.out.println(name);
     Users_List.add(name);
}
```

Comment: still same result . . .

Comment: Use getTextContent() instead getNodeValue()